# Store data when popup loses focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I would like to preserve user input data when user closes the extension's popup. Is there any reliable way to do this using [local storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) when the extension popup loses focus?

Comment: Use `onbeforeunload` listener or just do it immediately in `onchange` or `oninput` listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure that one out. When I was calling store functions directly from popup unload callback (detecting lost focus) it didn't work. Managed to do that when I was doing the storage in background page. Sample code below:

Background script:

```
function storeFormDataLocally(someData) {
   if (someData != null) {
      chrome.storage.local.set({
        'someDataKey': someData
      }, function() {
      console.log("data saved: " + someData)
     });
    }
   }
```

Popup:

```
addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
   var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
   var someData = "My data to store";
   background.storeFormDataLocally(someData);
}, true);
```